# How to return every Value inside Function1 into Function2. But before Returning Value(INSIDE OF FUNCTION1), Function2 Gets called

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the CODE:

```
from tkinter import *

#FUNCTION1
def nw1():
    w = Tk()
    w.geometry('400x440')

    l = Label(w, text='User Name').place(x=25, y=40)
    e = Entry(w, width=25)
    e.place(x=30, y=70)

    b = Button(w, text='Register', command=nw2) #COMMAND CALLED FUNCTION2 BEFORE "RETURN e"
    b.place(x=30, y=370)

    w.mainloop()
    return e

#FUNCTION2
def nw2():
    aaa = e.get()
    print(aaa)


nw1()
```

Suggest Changes so that Every value of FUNCTION1 can be accessible by FUNCTION2

Comment: define function 2 inside of the function1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two *classes* instead of two *functions* and give one class to another class as parent:

```py
from tkinter import *

#class1
class Nw1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.w = Tk()
        self.w.geometry('400x440')

        self.l = Label(self.w, text='User Name').place(x=25, y=40)
        self.e = Entry(self.w, width=25)
        self.e.place(x=30, y=70)

        self.b = Button(self.w, text='Register', command=Nw2) #COMMAND CALLED FUNCTION2 BEFORE "RETURN e"
        self.b.place(x=30, y=370)

        self.w.mainloop()

#class2
class Nw2(Nw1):
    def __init__(self):
        suer().__init__()
        aaa = self.e.get()
        print(aaa)


Nw2()
```

This way `Nw2` has all the class attributes of `Nw1` behind the `super()` function.

Comment: Yes, Declaring Nw1 as a parent class would do. But I'm not so familiar well with Initialization and the code you've written it still gives same error that i was getting

Comment: I edited the code so that now you only run `Nw2` class instead of `Nw1`, and the former has access to all the attributes of the latter. It gives a Tkinter error, but the classes work as you wished.